# I need to build external C++ solutions from a C# project

Tags: c#, cmd, build, msbuild

I'm working on a program that looks for solution files in a directory and then builds any you select on specified configurations and platforms, but I'm struggling to get it working in C#. The solutions I wish to build are C++, for what it's worth. I had a C++ version of the program but wanted to convert it for the added benefit of a Winforms GUI.

I'm happy to use any method available, and have tried the following two but each is presenting its own issues.

```
private void buildSolution1(string solution, Tuple<string, string> config)
{
     logEvent("Building " + solution + " on " + config.Item1 + "|" + config.Item2);
     ProjectCollection pc = new ProjectCollection();
     Dictionary<string, string> globalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     globalProperty.Add("Configuration", config.Item1);
     globalProperty.Add("Platform", config.Item2);
     globalProperty.Add("OutputPath", @"C:\data");

     BuildParameters bp = new BuildParameters(pc);
     BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.BeginBuild(bp);
     BuildRequestData buildRequest = new BuildRequestData(solution, globalProperty, "4.0", new string[] { "Build" }, null);
     BuildSubmission submission = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.PendBuildRequest(buildRequest);
     submission.ExecuteAsync(null, null);
     while (!submission.IsCompleted)
     {
         logEvent("building");
     }
     BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.EndBuild();
     logEvent(submission.BuildResult.OverallResult.ToString());
}

private void buildSolution2(string solution, string config)
{
     string devenv = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("\"%VS120COMNTOOLS%..\\ide\\devenv.com\"");
     string cmdArg = "/c" + devenv + " \"" + solution + "\" /build " + "\"" + config + "\"";
     System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
     System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
     startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
     startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\";
     startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
     startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     startInfo.Arguments = cmdArg;
     process.StartInfo = startInfo;
     process.Start();
     process.WaitForExit();
}
```

In either case, 'string solution' is passed in as a path to the solution I want to build, config is either a Tuple that contains the configuration and platform or a string that contains both separated by a '|' symbol. logEvent() is just a function that prints to my GUI.

buildSolution1():
This one just fails every time, I'm not sure why. It very quickly prints out 'building' a bunch of times and then reports the OverallResult as 'Failure'.

buildSolution2():
This one opens up CMD.exe with no parameters passed and doesn't run anything. Without the /c property at the start it just leaves the blank window open. With it it just opens and then closes again very quickly.

Hopefully somebody can assist me, thanks in advance for your time.

James

Comment: As for solution2, have you been able to compile through a manual (or batch file) command line procedure? If so, then it should work given the correct arguments and access rights are given to the starting process.

Comment: Hi Stefan, yes. The whole string evaluates to:
 /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\..\ide\devenv.com" "filepath" /build "Debug|Win32D3D11"
where filepath is the solution I'm trying to build. Putting this into a CMD.exe directly doesn't work with the '\c', but builds the solution if I omit it.
Thanks, James.

Comment: At a first look, in your second method, here -> `string cmdArg = "/c" + devenv +...` you have a space missing,should be `string cmdArg = "/c " + devenv +...`

Comment: Thanks Pikoh, I picked up on that when I was replying to Stefan and had already corrected it, unfortunately it hasn't made a difference to the success of the operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of anybody else with a similar problem, I was able to get the function working with the following code:

```
private void buildSolution(string solution, string config)
{
    string devenv = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("\"%VS120COMNTOOLS%..\\ide\\devenv.com\"");
    string cmdArg = "\"" + solution + "\" /build " + "\"" + config + "\"";
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\";
    startInfo.FileName = devenv;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    startInfo.Arguments = cmdArg;
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```